# BOOST graph queries

Tags: boost, graph

I have the following queries:

1. I want to know how to create a graph dynamically
2. How to manage multiple weights on a graph
3. How to find the distance from a particular node to another in a minimum spanning tree using kruskal.In kruskals the minimum spanning tree is output as a vector of edges.Hence the vertices are not explicitly stored. I do not know how to get the distance for say an example node 0 to the node furthest from it. I tried getting the vertices using sourc and target and then storing the verices in an array.After that, locating node 0 and from there iterating and reverse iterating through the vertices calculating the weights to find the largest diatance from the node 0. But I fell I'm using the most round about way of going about it.There must be a function for this, or perhaps a clevere way of going about this.
4. Does kruskal store the edges in the spanning tree in order of the spanning tree? Or at least is the first node of the first edge stored the actual first node? How can I get the order of the nodes in spanning tree in kruskals?
5. Similarly how can I get the weight of the spanning tree using Prim? The way I did it was to use the predecessor array where predecessors are stored and find what edge in weightsMap and add it.Is there an easier way? And in prims the distanceMap stores the distance from node 0 to the others in the original graph and not the spanning tree right?

Comment: Sorry about the formatting,my computer is super slow and not cooperating :|